# БИТРИКС Вывести меню с другого раздела

Tags: битрикс

Есть структура сайта:

- Главная
- Услуги
- Контакты

В услугах есть вложенные разделы:

- Услуга 1
- Услуга 2
- Услуга 3

Подскажите как вы вести верхнее меню состоящее только из страниц, дочерних к услугам? на всех страницах. Для того чтобы был быстрый доступ в любую услугу со всех страниц.
также меню может стать в последствии выпадающим, так как к каждой из услуг также могут прибавиться дочерние элементы.
Но в выпадением я разберусь, главное как вывести его))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Управлении структурой создайте новый тип меню (например, services). в корне сайта создайте файл .services.menu_ext.php, где получите массив необходимых ссылок меню из элементов инфоблока.

```
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
$aMenuLinksExt = [];
... некоторый код заполнения массива элементами ...
$aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinks, $aMenuLinksExt);
```

для вывода можете использовать стандартный компонент bitrix:menu, отметив опцию "USE_EXT" => "Y", разместив его, например, в header.php используемого шаблона.